# Prove that the number of words in a positive integer a in base Beta is 1 + ilog(a)/BPW where Beta = pow(2, BPW)

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

The number of digits (words) in a base Beta of any positive integer a is 1 + floor(log(a)) where the log is in base Beta. When the base Beta = 2 this is just the number of bits. That is 1 + lg(a) is the number of bits. I want to prove that
floor(log(a)) = floor(lg(a))/BPW
where BPW is the number of bits per word and lg is the log in base 2. So if 
Beta = pow(2, BPW) 
then I want to prove what always seemed obvious; the number of words in base Beta is 
1 + floor(lg(a)/BPW) = 1 + floor(lg(a))/BPW
but I am struggling with the floor function. How can I be sure that floor(lg(a)/BPW) = floor(lg(a))/BPW?

Comment: I found and proved the relationship floor(x/n) = floor(x)/n. That fixes my problem.

Comment: What about floor(1/2) and floor(1)/2? One is 0 and the other is 1/2.